# Make a tapped textbox as condition

Tags: c#

i want to communicate with an arduino, when i press start , i can see the values , now, i want to add an other condition , a tapped text in a text box

i want when i press "a" or any key ,then i press start, i execute a code

what is the specific event?

This is the code , of the button start

```
private void start_btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        Myport.PortName = "COM6";
        Myport.DataReceived += Myport_DataReceived;

        try
        {
            Myport.Open();
            while (true)
            {
                String data_rx = Myport.ReadLine();
                data_tb.Text = data_rx;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erreur");
        }
    }
```

This is the design form

Comment: Have you tried using a static variable, like lastPressedKey? You can assign new value on form's KeyDown event. And in your code, you can check for specific values. For example, if(lastPressedKey == a) { do something; } *Edit: And if that helps, let me know so that I can rephrase my question as an answer :)

Comment: There is not a lot of tapping going on as long as you write code that completely hangs the user interface.  Right now you cannot even *see* the data you receive.  You'll have to take care of the basics before you can move on, make the DataReceived event handler work first.  Then make it work so your Arduino doesn't hang the UI when it fire-hoses the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you want is the `TextChanged` event, which allows you to take the text in the textBox and make it a variable for later use. Assumnig that your code should only run if ANY button has been pressed. You can set the variable to be a `string?` which allows it to be null, then instantiate it as null.

This allows you to only set a value when the event is called and otherwise the string's value is null, which can allow you to ensure that a button has been pressed when it is not null.